# Confuse About Interface

Tags: c#, interface

I am quite new in C#.
And now while reading Interfaces. I am confused a lot. I have read on MSDN that we can not instantiate directly Interfaces. And later they wrote the following example.

```
Public interface ICat
{
   meow();
}
Public class Cat : ICat
{
   meow(){//do something }
}
////////////////////
static void main(){
Icat cat = new Cat();
Cat cat1 = nes Cat();
}
```

If we can not directly instantiate Interfaces then what is the meaning of **`Icat cat = new Cat();`** of this line.
And whats the difference between these two?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both the lines **instantiate an instance of `Cat` class**. The difference is that one of them is assigned to a **variable typed as `ICat`.**

```
ICat cat = new Cat();
Cat cat1 = nes Cat();
```

Because of that you can only call methods declared on `ICat` when accessing `Cat` instance via `cat` variable. You can access other members of `Cat` class when using `cat1`.

If you call `GetType` on any of the variables you'll get `Cat` back, because that's the type of the instance you have.

The other difference is, that if there is another class that implement `ICat` you can assign it's instance to `cat` variable, but you won't be able to assign it to `cat1` unless it inherits `Cat`:

```
Public class OtherCat : ICat
{
   meow(){//do something }
}

cat = new OtherCat();
// cat1 = new OtherCat(); // fails
```

Comment: If both lines instantiate a class of `Cat`. Then how can we instantiate an interface directly or indirectly?

Comment: You can't instantiate interface. You can only instantiate class that happen to implement that interface.

Comment: Then what's the difference between these two declaration??
`Icat cat = new Cat();` and `Cat cat1 = new Cat();`. Can you please further.

Comment: I already answered that question in my answer. I don't think I can make it any clearer.

Answer (score 5):

The interface in the first example is not being instantiated, but rather the type for the instantiated `Cat()` instance is being declared as type `ICat` as opposed to `Cat`.

In your particular example this isn't very interesting.  However, consider an interface that had the following declarations:

```
public interface ICat
{
   Meow();
   Run();
   Hunt();
}
```

Once this interface gets applied to multiple concrete types, behaviors can be applied across a variety of classes while consistently implementing the same behavior.

```
public class Lion : ICat 
{
    public void Roar();
    public void Meow();
    public void Run();
    public void Hunt();
}

public class Tiger : ICat 
{
    public void Meow();
    public void Run();
    public void Hunt();
}

ICat lion = new Lion();
ICat tiger = new Tiger();
```

Both concrete instances can benefit from all three methods guaranteed by the interface and ONLY the methods guaranteed by the interface unless casted to their concrete types.  This provides consistency across behaviors. Note however, this is not instantiating the interface.  It's only assigned the concrete instance to the shared interface type, which is permitted by the language.

As a result:

`lion.Run();` and `tiger.Run()` are both completely permissible.

However,

`lion.Roar()` would not compile, since it is not guaranteed by the interface.  That said, if you cast to the underlying concrete type that was actually instantiated and subsequently assigned to the interface, you can access that type's methods in addition to those of the interface.

```
((Lion)lion).Roar();
```

Likewise:

```
Lion concreteLion = new Lion();
```

Is not assigned to an interface when instantiated.  As a result it has direct access to all three methods guaranteed by the interface, and it can call `concreteLion.Roar()` without the need for a cast, since the instance has been assigned directly to the concrete type instead of the interface implemented by the Lion class.

Comment: If it is not being instantiated then how can we instantiate an Interface.?

Comment: @FawadWarraich You don't instantiate the interface.  An interface is only a contract.  It simply guarantees what types of concrete types that implement interfaces can do.  See if my updated answer gives you any more clarity :)

Answer (score 1):

First let's define what an `interface` is.

An `interface` can be thought of the same way as a contract in the sense that a class must implement anything defined within the given interface (contract). For example, say that I'm designing an `interface` to define the behaviour of a car.

The interface would contain two key behaviours.

1. Accelerate
2. Brake

**Example**

```
public interface ICar 
{
    void Accelerate();
    void Brake();
}
```

You can never instantiate an `interface` because an `interface` is only a contract, a definition of sorts of what a `class` must implement, a `class` that derives from an `interface` will implement all properties and methods defined within the `interface` from which it is deriving from. `Interfaces` are typically used to reduce dependencies in your code base, as demonstrated in this answer.

Carrying on with the example above, human beings drive cars, but there are thousands of different cars out there, and most are implemented differently, however, this shouldn't matter to human beings, if you have the ability to drive one car, you should be able to drive all cars. (Just generalizing here to keep things simple).

Thus what you need to do is instantiate a `class` that implements the `ICar` `interface` which anyone can then take for a drive...

```
void Main()
{
    Human jamesDoe = new Human();
    ICar car = new BMW();

    jamesDoe.TestDriveCar(car);
}

public interface ICar 
{
    void Accelerate();
    void Brake();
}  

public class BMW : ICar
{
    private int x;

    public void Accelerate()
    {
        new int[150].ToList()
                    .ForEach(i => { Console.WriteLine("{0} MPH", x++); Thread.Sleep(50); });

    }
    public void Brake()
    {
        new int[150].ToList()
                    .ForEach(i => { Console.WriteLine("{0} MPH", x--); Thread.Sleep(50); });
    }
}

public class Human
{
    public void TestDriveCar(ICar car)
    {
        car.Accelerate();
        car.Brake();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best description for me was this:

```
public interface IAnimal
{
    void ShowVoice();
}

public class Cat : IAnimal
{
    public void WiggleTail()
    {
        Console.Write("Wiggling tail...")
    }

    public void ShowVoice()
    {
        Console.Write("meow");
    }
}

public class Dog : IAnimal
{
    public void GivePaw()
    {
        Console.Write("Giving paw...")
    }
    public void ShowVoice()
    {
        Console.Write("woof");
    }
}

public static void main(){
    IAnimal cat = new Cat();
    IAnimal dog = nes Dog();
    cat.ShowVoice();
    //cat.WiggleTail(); - cannot do that on interface
    dog.ShowVoice();
    //dog.GivePaw(); - cannot do that on interface
    Cat catInst = new Cat();  
    Dog dogInst = new Dog(); 
    catInst.WiggleTail(); // you can do that because it is not an interface that we make call to
    dogInst.GivePaw(); //the same as with cat
    // catInst.GivePaw(); - cannot do this because it does not exist in the class
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When we define a interface, we define a generic case and when a class implements the interface then we define specific case. 
Lets take example

```
interface IVehicle 
{
    int noOfWheels;
    float price;
}

class TwoWheeler : IVehicle
{
    public TwoWheeler(float price)
    {
       this.noOfWheels = 2;
       this.price = price;
    }
}

class FourWheeler : IVehicle
{
     public FourWheeler(float price)
     {
         this.noOfWheels = 4;
         this.price = price;
     }
}

class VehicleBill
{
   IVehicle vehicle;

   public static void main()
   {
      Console.Write("enter your choice
              \n 1. Two wheeler
              \n 2. Four Wheeler");
      int ch = Conver.toInt32(console.Read());

     //Here we decide which class is to be used for initialization
      if(ch == 1)
        vehicle = TwoWheeler(80000);
     else if(ch == 2)
        vehicle = FourWheeler(500000);
   }
}
```